# How to set a property of a generic object in a list?

Tags: c#, generics

My class structure looks like this:

```
 public interface IStationProperty
   {
      int Id { get; set; }
      string Desc { get; set; }
      object Value { get;  }
      Type ValueType { get; }
   }

   [Serializable]
   public class StationProp<T> : IStationProperty
   {
      public StationProp()
      {
      }

      public StationProp(int id, T val, string desc = "")
      {
         Id = id;
         Desc = desc;
         Value = val;
      }

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Desc { get; set; }
      public T Value { get; set; }

      object IStationProperty.Value
      {
         get { return Value; }
      }

      public Type ValueType
      {
         get { return typeof(T); }
      }
   }
```

Which allows me to add multiple generic types to the same list like this:

```
var props = new List<IStationProperty>();
 props.Add(new StationProp<int>(50, -1, "Blah"));
 props.Add(new StationProp<bool>(53, true, "Blah"));
 props.Add(new StationProp<int>(54, 10, "Blah"));
```

What I would like to do now is be able to change just the value of an item in this list, without changing the Type.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you know an index of the item you want to change and you know what type it is. Then it goes like the following

```
(props[0] as StationProp<int>).Value = 5;
```

If you are not sure of its type

```
var item = props[i] as StationProp<int>;
if (item != null)
{
    item.Value = 5;
}
```

Does this answer your question? I'm not much sure what else would you like to achieve.

Comment: No need to cast; Value is part of the interface. He just needs to give it a setter.

Comment: @Gigi Yes, but then it involves boxing.